# Inheriting constructor and default constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

I'm reading the documentation on [Inheriting constructors here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration). There's an example:

```
struct B1 {
    B1(int);
};
struct D1 : B1 {
    using B1::B1;
// The set of inherited constructors is 
// 1. B1(const B1&)
// 2. B1(B1&&)
// 3. B1(int)

// D1 has the following constructors:
// 1. D1()
// 2. D1(const D1&) 
// 3. D1(D1&&)
// 4. D1(int) <- inherited
};
```

So it's clearly written `D1 has the following constructors: D1()`, i.e. default constructor. But when I'm trying to create an object:

`D1 d;`

And I have an error `use of deleted function 'D1::D1()'`. Is it a mistake in the documentation or I misunderstood something?

I tried gcc with c++14.

Comment: @POTEMKINDX You forgot to add `D1 d;` in `main()`.  If you did you would see it does not work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/220ea673061325fd

Comment: @POTEMKINDX you didnt call the constructor that causes the [error](http://ideone.com/dRGxbH)

Comment: @POTEMKINDX updated. Btw you didn't create an instance.

Comment: @nikitablack It is instresting that they say `D1()` exists as below that code block in the next code block they have `D1 e;          // Error: D1 has no default constructor`

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree. And on the Stroustroup's page (http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting) he also says that default constructor not created.

Comment: You're missing the crucial point that the default constructor is only synthesized if the base class *has a default constructor*, even if that involves using defaulted arguments.

Comment: @KerrekSB The problem is that the first example on cppreference says it should have a default in that example.

Comment: @NathanOliver Different standards.

Comment: @nikitablack Sorry for wrong fast comment. So topic about [default constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

Comment: A default constructor of `D` is implicitly declared as defaulted because there's no user-declared constructor, but it is then defined as deleted because the base class has no default constructor.

Comment: @T.C. The page and the first example have a note `(since C++11)(until C++17)`. Which standard do you mean?

Comment: As far as cppreference go, I'm somewhat inclined to rip out the whole `(until C++17)` block because CWG considers [P0136R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html) a DR against C++11. But that's new enough that I don't know if there's any compiler around that implements the new semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
struct B1                                                                                                                                                                                                
{
    B1(int){}
};

struct D1 : B1 {
    using B1::B1;
};


struct E
{
    E(){}
};


struct F
{
    F(int){}
};
```

---

If you try to write

```
E e;
```

it will build fine, but

```
F f;
```

will fail. By declaring a ctor which takes an `int`, you've effectively deleted the default ctor.

Your question's code follows the same principle. Once you've pulled in `B1`'s ctor into `D1` - you've effectively deleted its default ctor.

Answer (score -2):

A  bit further down that arcticle it says that it doesn't have a default constructor

D1 e;          // Error: D1 has no default constructor

Comment: so there is contradicting information on the page, but that does not explain, why `D1` has no default constructor in this case.

Comment: yeah I think it may be misleading , if you see the example in this arcticle http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor, because there is another constructor  then D() is not declared.